# Why JWPlayer used in Opera start parameter instead of the Range request param?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, opera, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Why JWPlayer used in Opera start=XXX.xx parameter instead of the Range: xxxxxx-xxxxx request param?

I have page with JWPlayer - http://new.arturik.net/ihtik/ .

```
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
         file: "stream.php",
         //file: "1.mp4",
//   file: "/qqq/output.mp4",
        image: "/qqq/img_002_.jpg",
          startparam: "start",

           width: 480,
        height: 270,
        type: 'mp4',


    });
```

In IE 11 and in the latest stable Google Chrome JWPlayer in the requests used Range:xxxx-xxxx param. But in the Opera 22.0 JWPlayer used ?start=xxx.xx param. Why in Opera 22.0 JWPlayer used ?start=xxx.xx param instead of the Range:xxxx-xxxx param?

P.S. stream.php is file from the http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Comment: http://new.arturik.net/ihtik/

Comment: This is running in html5 mode. Why bother with a psuedo streaming module when html5 video already supports this natively? The only point of having a pseudo streaming module is for Flash mode, because Flash doesn't support pseudo streaming without one.

Comment: Because it's works in Opera 22 incorrect, without pseudo streaming... Time seek does not work in JWPlayer in Opera 22

Comment: This is because you are using an mp4 file only, which Opera does not support in html5 mode. If you ended to webM as well, Opera would support this...